# Getting Started with the Web Client Software Factory But i don't find Solution picture?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I downloaded add start set up MVP Software, After setup finished, I don't find MVP C# solution (like: ASP .Net MVC solution, or ASP .Net Silverlight Solution) in list of project type?

I need a list of project list like start up ASP .Net solution for example:

If I click new project, .Net give me type of alternative solutions, So I choose one of them from list? I added silverlight in this list also MVC solution but I don't find MVP?

Please look second picture:

[Getting Started with the Web Client Software Factory](http://www.codeplex.com/websf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Getting_Started_Feb_2008&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Are you there or holidays for stackoverflow gurus?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install guidance automation extensions? If not, you need to install them. You will then have to uninstall the web client factory and reinstall it with the Guidance part (first folder on the installer, which is, by default, unchecked).

You can try a reinstall, but I have found this fails.

After you have it installed correctly, the project types appear under Guidance Packages. You will see Web Client Solution, either WAP or Website for both C# and VB.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i installed guidance automation extensions. but install.exe doesn't in package. Please look link [Click Please!!!](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/12/07/MVP-Pattern-guidance-from-patterns-amp-practices.aspx)